# Ruby- split array into subarrays of non-constant length

Tags: arrays, ruby

here is my issue:

I have a big array that I want to split into an array of arrays. These subarrays must be of lengths given by a second array.

Example

```
x=[*1..10]

y=[1,4,2,3]
```

I am seeking `output=[[1],[2,3,4,5],[6,7],[8,9,10]]`

Is there a rubyistic trick to do this?

Thanks for your assistance :)

Comment: _"I have a big array"_ – okay, but `[1..10]` is an array with a _single_ element: the range `1..10`. Maybe you wanted `x = [*1..10]`?

Comment: @Stefan Makes a good point, you can change it to an array with `(1..10).to_a`

Comment: absolutely right, edited as such (ruby novice here :)).

Comment: @cdDC No probs, we've all got to start somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

You could try `shift` which gives you the first element in an array, removing it from the start.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.shift
# 1
a
# [2,3,4]
```

It also takes an argument for the amount to shift off the array.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.shift(2)
# [1,2]
a
# [3,4]
```

So for your arrays...

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [1,4,2,3]

z = y.map do |length|
  x.shift(length)
end 

z
# [[1], [2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```

- `shift` with an argument will return an array of that many elements taken off the start of the array. The opposite of this is `pop`, which works in the same way, but takes elements from the end of the array.
- `map` will iterate through the array, like `each`, but put the result of each iteration into a new array.
- So iterating through your array of lengths, we'll grab the first few from the array.

---

**Addendum:** Some commenters have expressed concern that this method mutates the initial variable. (after this  process, x will be an emtpy array, because it's all been shifted out).

If you needed to use `x` again after splitting it up, you could use `dup` to keep an intact copy.

```
x2 = x.dup
x2
# [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

z = y.map do |length|
  x2.shift(length)
end 

x
# [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
x2
# []
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My subarrays are not of constant length- can I supply a vector of lengths as argument?

Comment: @cdDC Sorry, I misread your question at first. Here's a solution.

Comment: Note that `shift` will also modify the receiver, thus leaving an empty `x`. You might want to `dup` it beforehand.

Comment: Mmm that is a smooth solution. I did not know that shift could take an argument. Thank you very much!

Comment: @cdDC No probs, these things come in handy quite a lot. It's worth reading the ruby docs for Enumerable, and Array to expand your ruby toolkit. Just skimming through API docs until you see something interesting is a surprisingly rewarding task.

Comment: Nice. @AJFaraday, are there possible unintended effects of the mutation with `shift`? If the array will be used again, it won't be the same thing, but what if it wasn't used again?

Comment: @DaryllSantos Yes, that is a possibility. If you want to reuse the array, you'd first set a new variable with `dup`, so you modify one copy, and have one un-mutated copy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `slice!` method along with an array initializer block:

```
x = (1..10).to_a    # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [1, 4, 2, 3]
c = Array.new(y.length) {|i| x.slice!(0...y[i])}    # [[1], [2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```

or with `map`, as pointed out by @Stefan:

```
c = y.map { |i| x.slice!(0, i) }
```

Comment: Or `y.map { |i| x.slice!(0, i) }` which is essentially `y.map { |i| x.shift(i) }`

Answer (score -1):

Using explicit enumerators.

```
enumx = x.each
enumy = y.each

Array.new(y.size) { enumy.next.times.with_object([]) { |_, o| o << enumx.next } }
 #=> [[1], [2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```

To improve readability we could wrap it up in a method.

```
def taker n, enum
  n.times.with_object([]) { |_, o| o << enum.next }
end

enumx = x.each
enumy = y.each

Array.new(y.size) { taker enumy.next, enumx }
 #=> [[1], [2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```